# Why is my Crucial M550 or MX100 drive so slow in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, dell, ssd, storage, firmware

Recently I replaced the Samsung SSD (Dell OEM) in my notebook with a Crucial M550. Now I see very very poor write performance. Maximum of 80 MB/s sequential writes and the system freezes up for minutes when transferring large files. My notebook is the Dell Latitude E7240.

Also with a Crucial MX100 drive in another Dell notebook (E6230) I have the same issue.

It's really just raw write performance that's below anything seen in reviews/benchmarks online.

When I put the SSD in my desktop it's performing much better! Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was down voted, but myself I found that some hardware/system info would be needed to debug and finding related posts with same issue. Info like: kernel version, driver in use, some dmesg outputs related to this drives, `hdparm -I` output.

Comment: @user.dz Yes, I self-answered my question with the relevant information already.

Comment: I didn't notice that you have posted the answer in same time, that' s ok. Otherwise, this question lucks info if was posted alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me quite a while to get this sorted, because it's two factors coming into play here.

1. Dell sends a full powersaving command during boot (BIOS POST) to the drive if you boot it on battery power. No matter if you later plug back in the AC, power savings will still be turned on. We can work around this with a custom boot command.
2. Crucial messed up TRIM with NCQ, resulting in data loss. In Linux, NCQ is disabled hardcoded (blacklisted) for these drives. A firmware upgrade and a kernel update is required to fix it.

### Work around the power saving

With `hdparm` you can check whether your drive is indeed affected.

```
# sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level      = X
```

With X = 128, the power savings is active (low performance), with 254 it's turned off (high performance). You can verify with fully shutting down your laptop and turning it on with AC plugged in (before powering on) that it is 254. And when booting without AC plugged in, this is 128.

To manually disable power savings again when Ubuntu starts, put this in `/etc/rc.local` (above the `exit 0` line!):

```
/sbin/hdparm -B254 /dev/sda
```

### Enable NCQ: firmware update & kernel update

Crucial really messed it up in the release of the M550/MX100 drives with NCQ and TRIM. If a TRIM command enters the queue with NCQ turned on, data corruption can happen. Windows does not perform TRIM commands together with other I/O operations in the queue, but these are handled separately. Therefore Windows users aren't affected by this terrible data loss effect, but Ubuntu users were.

Linux kernel developers therefore put all recent Crucial SSDs on the NCQ blacklist. Without NCQ, performance will be much slower.

The good news is that a recent firmware update (MU02) by Crucial fixes the issue. The kernel however, only got aware of this change very recently with the blacklist narrowed down to the MU01 firmware ([here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/ata/libata-core.c?id=v4.0#n4213)). This is fixed in Linux 4.0 and has arrived as a backport in Ubuntu 15.04 as a kernel update through the vivid-updates channel.